# How to chmod files that have a specific set of permissions

Tags: chmod

I want to find all files in a folder that have `-rw-r-----` (640? is that the right code?) permissions, and change them all to have `-rw-rw-rw-` instead.  How do I do this, with chmod?

I know I could do the whole folder with

```
sudo chmod -R 666 /path/to/folder
```

but I think (perhaps mistakenly?) that it would be more efficient to just do the ones that actually need it?

Alternatively, rather than specifically looking for `-rw-r-----`, I could chmod any file that doesn't have 666 already?  Would that be better?

Comment: You definitely do not want to do `chmod -R 666`, since it would remove the executable bit from the folder, making it unbrowseable. `chmod -R a=rwX` maybe.

Comment: Yes that just occurred to me - I think `chmod -R +r,+w` might be best.  There shouldn't be any executable stuff in that folder anyway.

Comment: If there's nothing executable, including no subfolders, no need for `-R`, just do `chmod 666 /path/*`.

Comment: Just to be clear, yes `rw-r-----` == 640

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
find /path/to/folder -perm 640 -exec chmod 666 {} \;
```

Comment: To find only files (not oddly-specified directories) with permissions 640, add `-type f`
eg:  `find -type f /path/to/folder -perm 640 -exec chmod 666 {} \;`

Comment: And don't forget about using `+` instead of `\;` with `-exec` so it only runs `chmod` once, instead of separately for each file.